# export data from mixpanel to my react project

Tags: reactjs, mixpanel

I am trying to get the data from mixpanel into my react project. I have below code. But I am getting unauthorized error. can someone help me with the call

```
    const API_SECRET = 'api secret';
    const API_KEY = 'project token';
    const apiUrl = 'https://data.mixpanel.com/api/2.0/export?from_date=2023-11-05&to_date=2023-11-08'  
   
    fetch(apiUrl, {
    mode: 'no-cors',        
    headers: {
        accept: 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Basic ${btoa(`${API_KEY}:${API_SECRET}`)}`,
    }
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        }
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');
      })
      .then(data => {
        // Handle the data from the API response
        console.log('API Response:', data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // Handle errors here
        console.error('Error:', error);
      });
```